# htaccess rewrite converted to nginx configuration has loop

Tags: nginx, .htaccess

I migrated a site from a apache server to a nginx server and need to convert the .htaccess rules.

I have one rewriterule as it was in .htaccess:

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=example.com
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.+)\.(\w+)
 RewriteRule ^/?$ ?q=landingpage/%1%2 [L,QSA]
```

This will do the following, to be used for domain aliases:

- if the domain is not example.com (i.e. foo.bar)
- get variables before and after the dot (foo bar)
- serve foo.bar?q=landingpage/foobar

And I converted it to the following nginx configuration:

```
location / {
    if ($http_host != "example.com"){
    rewrite ^/?$ /?q=landingpage/%1%2 break;
    }
}
```

However, this is

1. incomplete since it is not defining the variables (foo and bar)
2. it results in a loop where the url gets very long repeating
   itself
3. it uses 'ifs' which is not recommended (it appears that
   try_files is better)

I can't get this to work. I'm new to nginx, and would like assistance in making this work, thanks.

Comment: Please describe your end state properly, you haven't said what you want to happen, and you can't assume Nginx people will understand Apache syntax. Looks like some kind of a rewrite when the home page is hit, though I don't know where your %1 and %2 parameters are coming from because I can't see a regular expression matching group.

Comment: The problem here is that the original Apache rewrite rules don't make any sense. What are they supposed to do? If you don't understand what you need to do, you have approximately zero chance of success.

Comment: Michael, the original Apache rewrite rule works as follows: any domain name which is not example,com such as testing.com will stay the same in the url, but what will be served as testing.com/landingpage/testingcom

Comment: The purpose is to rewrite domain aliases to landingpages in the site

Comment: Hmm. It's probably better if you put the dots back in.

Comment: You mean remove the second condition? Then the rule wont recognize the variable $1